# How to get hidden node value programmatically?

Tags: nodes

I am new to Drupal so this question might be stupid or impossible. I am sorry for that.

I am using the [Hidden Nodes](https://drupal.org/project/hidden_nodes) module in order to make nodes visible to some users, and not visible to anonymous users.

I also have a custom module where I get some nodes nid ($node->nid->value()), titles, and other stuff programmatically.

Now, I also need to get the hidden_node value for the nodes, but I can't get it because its not a node field.

Sorry if this seems confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: See `function hidden_nodes_schema()` in hidden_nodes.install to get a grip on how does this module store it's data. Yes, it's there, just checked ;)

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot, but one more question. 

Is it possible to get the node->hidden value, if I've previously done entity_metadata_wrapper? Because is says that $node_wrapper->hidden->value() does not exists.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a forum, if you have another question [ask it as a question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).